# Create a border in a dynamically created div when clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, dynamic

Please help!!!
I make a game quiz with flags as an exercise in JavaScript. In a container I create dynamically divs with the country names as choices. When the div is clicked the program iterates an array of objects with the right answers and if the clicked div's id is in there I want to add to the div a green border. In case of wrong a red border. I have this code:

```js
x = document.getElementById("container").childNodes;
x[x.length-1].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    for(i=0; i<realNeighbours.length; i++){
        if(realNeighbours[i]['code3'].includes(e.target.id)  ){
            e.target.style.border = 'green';
            console.log(this.innerHTML);
        }else{
            e.target.style.border = 'red';
            console.log('wrong')
        }
    }
});
```

When I click a div the borders doesn't show either for  wrong or right answer and in the console when I click a "Wrong" country shows the wrong message but when I click a right country shows the name (as it should), but also shows the 'Wrong' again with some number in the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your border is probably 0px width. Try setting it this way:

```
e.target.style.border = '1px solid green'
```

Comment: To dig deeper into the code is a matter of a different question. Create a New Question for this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `if/else` is running for each element, so for every wrong element, it's going into your `else` statement.

You could do something like this instead, using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
// ISO-3166 country codes collection https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iso:pub:PUB500001:en
const matches = [
    // { "code": "AF", "code3": "AFG", "name": "Afghanistan", "number": "004" },
    // { "code": "AL", "code3": "ALB", "name": "Albania", "number": "008" },
    // { "code": "DZ", "code3": "DZA", "name": "Algeria", "number": "012" },
    // { "code": "HU", "code3": "HUN", "name": "Hungary", "number": "348" },
    { "code": "LV", "code3": "LVA", "name": "Latvia", "number": "428" },
    { "code": "LY", "code3": "LBY", "name": "Libya", "number": "434" },
    { "code": "PT", "code3": "PRT", "name": "Portugal", "number": "620" },
    { "code": "TH", "code3": "THA", "name": "Thailand", "number": "764" }
];

const nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
[...nodes].forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (matches.find(d => d["code3"] === e.target.id) !== undefined){
      e.target.style.border = "2px solid green";
    }
    else {
      e.target.style.border = "2px solid red";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="AFG">Afghanistan</li>
  <li id="ALB">Albania</li>
  <li id="DZA">Algeria</li>
  <li id="HUN">Hungary</li>
  <li id="LVA">Latvia</li>
  <li id="LBY">Libya</li>
  <li id="PRT">Portugal</li>
  <li id="THA">Thailand</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @mat1, I've updated the code to match the data format you had with country codes and etc. You can use **Array.prototype.find()** to filter your array of objects. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the elements are not list items, is dynamically created divs inside a container. Each div has 2 p elements. I want a click function to select either the div either the p elements and if the div's id is in the array(matches) then the whole div takes green border and not around p elements(if clicked), else red border. my html is like: ```<div class='container><div>dynamically created with <p></p><p></p></div><div>dynamically created with <p></p><p></p></div><div>dynamically created with <p></p><p></p></div></div>```